# How can I pass my own parameter to the callback function in JQuery pagination plugin?

Tags: jquery, pagination

According to the definition of callback in [JQuery pagination plugin's](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination#readme) documents. It seems that it only get tow parameters of its own.So, how can I pass extra parameter to the callback function.

> callback
>
> A callback function that is called
>   when a user clicks on a pagination
>   link. The function receives two
>   parameters: the new page index and the
>   pagination container (a DOM element).
>   If the callback returns false, the
>   event propagation is stopped. Default
>   value: function(){return false;}. This
>   callback function is essential for the
>   functionality of the pagination! It
>   should contain code that updates your
>   content. For a fast user experience
>   you should NOT load content via AJAX
>   in this function. Instead, pre-load
>   some content pages and switch between
>   them with this function.

e.g code of plugin usage [ from its demo]:

attach pagination plugin:

```
$("#News-Pagination").pagination(122, {
    items_per_page:20,
    callback:pageselectCallback
});
```

callback function:

```
    /**
     * Callback function that displays the content.
     *
     * Gets called every time the user clicks on a pagination link.
     *
     * @param {int}page_index New Page index
     * @param {jQuery} jq the container with the pagination links 
     *                 as a jQuery object
     */
     function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
       var new_content 
         = $('#hiddenresult div.result:eq(' + page_index + ')').clone();
       $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
       return false;
     }
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom wrapper function, as is common in JS, to achieve that.

```
callback: function(jq1, jq2, ..., jqN) {
  return pageselectCallback(your1, your2, jq1, jq2, ..., jqN);
}
```

Here *jq1* through *jqN* are the parameters given by jQuery pagination plugin, while *your1*, *your2* are parameters you specify yourself.

**IMPORTANT:** The above is not valid JS syntax due to the ellipsis ..., - change to match your situation