# Is a wrapper function syntax invalid in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894332/how-can-i-pass-my-own-parameter-to-the-callback-function-in-jquery-pagination-pl), the replier offers a correct and well structured solution to a problem.

However, he also argues that the suggested approach (i.e. making a wrapper for a callback function) isn't a valid JavaScript. That begs three questions.

1. Is that so?
2. What bad things can happen if applied?
3. What would be a valid JavaScript to resolve that issue?

Comment: He was just saying, "Don't copy and paste this because it's only an example to build off of".

Comment: I think the main point is that there's lots of different ways to declare a function and he chose the 'prototype' style one, which you might not necessarily need to use.

Comment: @Deryck Oh, my... Apparently I'll start off the year by being slow... But of course! On the other hand, that's sort of implied that he provides an approach and solution-direction. Not the actual code to paste in. The OP needs to do some work themselves, right? :)

Comment: @johnnycardy What would be other(s) way(s) to do that?

Comment: Yo but on the real - +1 for having the only proper use of the English language on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @KonradViltersten
function callback(...){ ... } OR
var callback = function(...){...} OR
callback: function(...){...}

Answer (score 5):

The `...` is not valid syntax. There are two solutions:

First, you could manually list out a lot of parameters:

```
callback: function (jq1, jq2, jq3, jq4, jq5, jq6) {
  return pageselectCallback(your1, your2, jq1, jq2, jq3, jq4, jq5, jq6);
}
```

This of course won't work if there are more than six parameters. To fix this, you can use the [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method, which takes an array of parameters:

```
callback: function () {
    return pageselectCallback.apply(null, 
        Array.prototype.concat.call([your1, your2], arguments));
}
```

Comment: Turns out `[1, 2].concat(arguments)` gives you `[1, 2, Arguments]`. Oops. The `arguments` object behaves in weird ways.

Comment: You can simplify the concat call to `[].concat.apply([y1,y2], arguments)`

Answer (score 2):

The example code in the answer is not valid. (`, ...,`)
But the solution is valid.

Comment: Updated to fix the comment :)